# jcraft.jsch using ssh Key

Tags: java, function, ubuntu, ssh, jsch

After reading the risks in cause of using : session.setConfig( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" );
i want to change it.

So I get the public ssh key on a ubuntu 20.04 with : ssh-keyscan -t rsa mydomain.xx in Putty

I got a key and use it like :

```
        String  khost = "mydomain.xx ssh-rsa AAAAB3...eLaWw5aREM=";

        jsch.setKnownHosts(new ByteArrayInputStream(khost.getBytes("UTF8")));
       
        session = jsch.getSession( user, sftpServer, portno );
        session.setPassword( pass );
        session.setConfig( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes" );
        session.connect();
```

But i got this Exception:

```
Mai 14, 2021 12:30:04 PM org.joobsoft.vt.SYS.SFtpToolsClass getimage
 java.io.IOException: Fehler beim Oeffnen des SFTP-Channel zur SFTP-Session mit 'user' an 'host.mydomain.xx': 
at org.joobsoft.vt.SYS.SFtpToolsClass.connectServer(SFtpToolsClass.java:176)
at org.joobsoft.vt.SYS.SFtpToolsClass.getimage(SFtpToolsClass.java:421)
at org.joobsoft.vt.APP.CONTROLLER.PVA00000.YouController.getinfopic(YouController.java:256)
at org.joobsoft.vt.APP.CONTROLLER.PVA00000.YouController.initdynamicnodes(YouController.java:101)
at org.joobsoft.vt.APP.CONTROLLER.PVA00000.YouController.injectMainController(YouController.java:66)
at org.joobsoft.vt.APP.CONTROLLER.PVA00000.AppStartController.initialize(AppStartController.java:82)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
at org.joobsoft.vt.APP.CONTROLLER.PVA00000.LoginController.CB_LOGIN(LoginController.java:295)
at org.joobsoft.vt.APP.CONTROLLER.PVA00000.LoginController.handle_CB_LOGIN(LoginController.java:162)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1859)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.keyReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:163)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4064)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2123)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2591)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: host.mydomain.xx
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:789)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:345)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at org.joobsoft.vt.SYS.SFtpToolsClass.connectServer(SFtpToolsClass.java:127)
... 71 more
```

I have seen the end of the String: REM= and have try to del this, but their is no different.

Comment: are you connecting to `host.mydomain.xx` (from the error message) or `mydomain.xx` (from the code). I think the hostname should match

Comment: Yes, you see the variable sftpServer = host.domain.xx . Is the answer for your question. For Info: it runs with StrictHostKeyChecking = no

Comment: For StrictHostKey=yes you must have an entry in the knownhosts data _for the host you are connecting to_. An entry (or entries) for _other_ host(s) is(are) ignored. Only an entry for the _same_ host is relevant. Also note getting the key with ssh-keyscan isn't any more secure than StrictHostKey=no; a criminal or enemy can feed the wrong key to ssh-keyscan just as they could to an actual connection attempt.

Comment: OK, but which way is safe